# When I share an SharePoint website to external user, can I have it so they don't have to sign in?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, authentication, sharing, external-sharing

I'm trying to share out a communications page and I'm sending an invite out but I would like it so they don't have to sign in, is this possible?

Comment: Hi, did you try my solution given below? let me know if you need any further help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Site pages can be shared using anonymous links that don't require sign-in. Anyone with an access to the link can view the site pages. The links are valid until you disable them, or they expire (if an expiration date was set).

You can use "Anyone with the link" option while sharing site pages to external users.

For more information, follow below Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Change the sharing settings for a site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-external-sharing-site)
2. [External sharing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview)
3. [Manage sharing settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)